# How to use AVPlayer and Image in UITableViewCell depending upon the response from my API

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, video, avplayer

**Functionality** : I need to implement a tableview where the cells will have either an image or a video depending upon the category in my API.

**Whats happening** : The images and video are displayed well but when a cell with video is displayed it replaces all the cell with AVPlayer, the cells with the images too.

**Code** : -

```
(in cellForRowAtIndexPath - )

if (![dict[@"video_360x290"] isEqualToString:@""]) {

 AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dict[@"video_360x290"]]];
 AVPlayer *playVideo = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
 cell.playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
 cell.playerViewController.player = playVideo;
 cell.playerViewController.player.volume = 10;
 cell.playerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.vPost.frame.size.width, cell.vPost.frame.size.height);
 [cell.vPost addSubview:cell.playerViewController.view];
 [playVideo play];

}
else{
 [cell.iPost sd_setImageWithURL:dict[@"image"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageNotAvailable"] options:SDWebImageHighPriority];
}
```

***What i Need : I need that cell with images displays images and cell with video displays video***
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let TableViewCell Class name is **ImageVideoCell**

Create **THREE** cells from Storyboard in TableView, 1 for Image and 2 for Video and change cell identifier. For Image Cell change Identifier to "**ImageCell**" and for Video Cell change Identifier to "**VideoCell1**" and "**VideoCell2**" add same tableViewCell Class on all cells like here **ImageVideoCell**.

And in Controller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  // MARK: - Outlets
  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

  // MARK: - Properties
  var imgVideos = [ImgVideo?]()
  var player : AVPlayer?

  // MARK: - View Life Cycle
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // API call to get Images and videos in TableView
    tableView.dataSource = self
}


 override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)

    if player?.isPlaying == true {
        self.player?.pause()
        self.player = nil
    }
}

// MARK: - Action
@IBAction func play_pauseButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    guard let video = imgVideos[sender.tag] else { return } // get video URl here
    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)) as? ImageVideoCell else { return }

    // if Video is already Playing And User want to Pause it then
    if player?.isPlaying ?? false && video.isSelected {
        player?.pause()
        sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "play-button"), for: .normal)

    }
    // if the Video is pause and User want to Play it again
    else if player?.isPlaying ?? true == false && video.isSelected {
        player?.play()
        sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "media-pause"), for: .normal)

    }
    // Play any other Video 
    else {

        for (index, video) in audios.enumerated() {

            if video?.isSelected ?? false {
                video?.isSelected = false
                tableView.beginUpdates()
                tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .none)
                tableView.endUpdates()
            }
        }
        video.isSelected = true
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)], with: .none)
        tableView.endUpdates()

        guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)) as? ImageVideoCell else { return }
        cell.play_pauseButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "media-pause"), for: .normal)



        play(videoUrl: vedio.url ?? "") // Play is a function for playing Videos
    }

}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = ImageVideoCell()
   if Image {
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ImageCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageVideoCell
   // Display Img
   }else {

     if video?.isSelected ?? false {
      cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VideoCell1", for: indexPath) as! ImageVideoCell
     }else {
      cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VideoCell2", for: indexPath) as! ImageVideoCell
     }

   }

   cell.play_pauseButton.tag = indexPath.row
   cell.play_pauseButton.setImage(audio?.isSelected ?? false ? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "media-pause") : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "play-button"), for: .normal)
   return cell
  }
}


// MARK: - AVPlayer
  extension AVPlayer {
     var isPlaying: Bool {
         return ((rate != 0) && (error == nil))
     }
  }
```

Comment: Most welcome :) . If it worked perfectly then please vote. thanks

Comment: hi..well it didn't worked too. The player appears with the play button but it doesn't play on loading of cell as well as on clik of it

Comment: Hi, Are you adding PLAYER on every cell in CELLForRow ?? If you are doing like this then it cause Memory Leak issue and it probably goes wrong. So just create one Button action and when user Play any video then Add Player otherwise dont add .

Comment: Let me Edit my Answer.

Comment: AS i have already worked with this type of functionality for Playing Audios in tableView, and now i have Just EDIT it for yours. Check it. Thanks